# Does Green's (first) identity hold for Weak Derivatives?

Tags: calculus, integration, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Recall Green's First Identity:

> $$\int_{\Omega}v \Delta u \  (d\Omega) =\int_{\partial \Omega}v  (\nabla u )\vec{n} \   d (\partial \Omega) - \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v \  (d \Omega)$$

Which requieres $u \in C^2(\Omega)$ and $v \in C^1(\Omega)$.

So the question is simple: Does this apply to weak derivatives? i.e. Can we weaken the conditions given to be $u \in H^2(\Omega)$ and $v \in H^1(\Omega)$?

**Aditional information:** I am reading *Sobolev Spaces, Functional Analysis and Partial Differential Equations*, By Haim Brezis, the proof of Theorem 9.25, which deals with the regularity of the weak solutions for the Laplacian problem.

It is stated, under the assumption that $u \in H^2(\Omega)$, $f \in H^1(\Omega)$ and $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ that from: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \nabla u \nabla(D\varphi)+ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u(D \varphi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f (D \varphi) 
$$

We deduce: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \nabla (Du) \nabla(\varphi)+ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(Du)\varphi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (Df) \varphi 
$$

Which I could show If I could apply Green's First Identity restricting the integrals to the (compact $\Rightarrow$) bounded support of $\varphi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An identity that is originally proved for smooth functions can be extended to a Sobolev space provided that both sides are continuous with respect to the Sobolev norm. This is a general topological fact: if two continuous functions agree on a dense subset, then they agree everywhere.

In the case of linear expressions like $u\mapsto \int \varphi \nabla u$, or bilinear like $(u,v) \mapsto \int u\Delta v$, continuity is equivalent to boundedness.

Consider the identity that you stated, 
$$\int_{\Omega}v \Delta u   =\int_{\partial \Omega}v  (\nabla u )\vec{n}   - \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v  $$
On the left we have a continuous function on $H^2\oplus H^1$, because 
$$\left|\int_{\Omega}v \Delta u \right|\le \|v\|_{L^2} \|\Delta u\|_{L^2} \le C\|v\|_{H^1} \| u\|_{H^2} $$ 
Similarly, $\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v $  is bounded. The boundary term  is okay on sufficiently smooth domains (Lipschitz is enough), because the trace operator is bounded from $H^1(\Omega)$ to $L^2(\partial \Omega)$.  So we get
$$
\left| \int_{\partial \Omega}v  (\nabla u )\vec{n}  \right|
\le \|v\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}
\le C\|v\|_{H^1} \| u\|_{H^2} 
$$

In the book the boundary term doesn't appear since $\varphi$ is compactly supported.